# How do I broadcast my Node JS app locally (LAN)

Tags: javascript, node.js, hosting, lan

I am running a node JS app on my Ubuntu machine and it works, I can visit localhost:8080 on that machine and the app displays.  Any other machine on the network however cannot reach it.

CODE:

```
const portNumber = 8080
let app = express()

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

app.get('/', function(req, res) { res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/stocks.html') })

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

let httpServer = http.createServer(app)

httpServer.listen(portNumber, function(){ console.log('listening on port:: ' + portNumber) })
```

etc...

I was using port 4023 at first but switched to 8080.  I have also looked into my network diagnostics to specifically allow this app but cannot find the options in my AT&T network config

[AT&T firewall config page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6U7G.png)

I installed pm2 and nginx but those aren't necessarily going to help me with this problem until I can get this port unblocked/ all ports unblocked on my LAN.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "Any other machine on the network however cannot reach it." So are you trying to access it from the other machine via the machines IP?

Comment: No, I am trying to reach it from localhost or 127.0.0.1.  But I did try that just in case it would work but no luck as I'm sure is expected right?

Answer (score 0):

You often need to bind to `"0.0.0.0"` in order for connections outside your machine to work, as in:

```
httpServer.listen(portNumber, "0.0.0.0", ...)
```

The default bind is to *localhost* only, which is of no use for other machines.

Your network firewall is irrelevant here, it doesn't normally block internal traffic. That's up to the individual machines.

Comment: Just tried this, same problem

Comment: It's worth checking with a tool like `lsof` that the port is open on the right IP binding.

Comment: OK, I did just try that tool but it spits out a whole load of lines that are indecipherable to me.  I do see a lot of 'node' processes/files but no IP addresses.  Anything in particular I should be looking for?

Comment: You can focus it down with `lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P -n | grep 8080`. More [examples here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26887/lsof-and-listening-ports).

Comment: What's interesting is your code does bind properly, as in I see this: `TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)` meaning it *is* listening on all (`*`) addresses. As to why the other machine can't connect, try giving it a poke with `nmap` or even `telnet`. It's also worth checking with `ping` that you can connect in the first place, and that you're using your machine's *local* address, not external "internet" IP.

Comment: so i tried your focused lsof here is the result:

Comment: node 97179 myusername 22u IPv4 208927            0t0 TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)

Comment: If I wanted to ping my linux machine from another i would ping its "inet" ip correct?  I tried this and did get a response.

Comment: Also, I tried nmap on the inet ip and it said 'host is up" as well as some other information.  Telnet did not connect.  "Timed out", "unable to connect to remote host"

Comment: What I'm saying here is that each machine has a LAN address, typically `10.x.x.x` or `192.168.x.x`, which is *not* accessible from the general internet, but *is* available locally *if* both machines are on the same "subnet". Check which IP each machine has, such as via `ipconfig` or `ifconfig` or equivalent, and then verify you can ping from one to the other, then check TCP ports using `curl` to access your Node HTTP process.